# How do I validate/log my traffic passing through tor?

Tags: ubuntu, network-configuration, proxy, privoxy

I'm using the Tor client on Ubuntu in conjunction with a Privoxy proxy to forward HTTP traffic to SOCKS5.

I would like to validate that my setup is actually working but can't figure out how to monitor traffic passing through Tor or between the two proxies.

Any suggestion on how to do this is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to figure out and how did you set up the system?

Comment: I'm using this as a proxy for standard http requests and I'm trying to validate that it's actually passing through tor and not just being sent out to the internet.

Comment: How about visiting https://check.torproject.org/

Comment: What does check.torproject.org say?

Comment: running `curl --proxy localhost:8118 https://check.torproject.org` returns a bunch of html with the phrase "Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor." so I guess it works. However if possible I would still like to monitor all the traffic passing through Tor.